# How to store the output of a for loop into a csv file in R?

Tags: r

I've a couple of for loops:

```
for (i in 1:length(v1))
{  
  v2[i] <- subset(file1, srl == v1[i], FlrGrp)
}
```

and

```
for(i in 1:length(v1))
{
  print(v1[i])
  print(v2[i])
}
```

and v1[] is a vector of some numbers..

Now the output of the second for loop is as follows:

```
[1] 789
[[1]]
[1] Pg        D115    D06    Slz
27 Levels:  DD D004 D010 D022 D023 D103 D108 D113 D115 D211 D214 ... Slz

[1] 787
[[1]]
[1] D010           Hs/Cn
27 Levels:  DD D004 D010 D022 D023 D103 D108 D113 D115 D211 D214 ... Slz

[1] 949
[[1]]
[1] Hs/Cn D06          
27 Levels:  DD D004 D010 D022 D023 D103 D108 D113 D115 D211 D214 ... Slz
```

Now I want to create a csv file using write.csv file where the output will be stored as follows:

```
srl FlrGrp
789 Pg,D115,D06,Slz
787 D010,Hs/Cn
949 Hs/Cn,D010
```

How to achieve this in R using write.csv or anything more helpful?? 
(Please note that I'm also trying not to include the message that says every time - `27 Levels: DD D004 D010 D022 D023 D103 D108 D113 D115 D211 D214 ... Slz`

Comment: a `dput` of the output of the second for loop wld be helpful

Comment: you can try using `sink(output.csv)` and instead of printing the vectors, use `cat(v2, sep =",", fill = TRUE)`

Comment: I used sink() and the entire output just went into the file.. as expected.. But how do I change it to the way I posted in the question?? Any way to control/manipulate the sink() function output??